# Use dynamic routes while maintaining existing file structure with Next.js

Tags: reactjs, next.js, dynamic-routing

I currently have a file structure like so within the 'src' directory:

```sh
|____pages
| |____FirstPage
| | |____First.js
| | |____index.js
| |____SecondPage
| | |____Second.js
| | |____index.js
| |____FirstDynamicRoutePage
| | |____PageToRenderOnDynamicRoute.js
| | |____index.js
```

I would like to keep this file structure and use dynamic routing. For example, the route for 'PageToRenderOnDynamicRoute.js" will be something like '/page/pageType/:pageId/otherSlug/:slug'.

I am aware that I can use the dynamic routing provided by Next.js, but I do not want to use the necessary file structure of:

```sh
| |____page
| | |____pageType
| | | |____[pageId]
| | | | |____otherSlug
| | | | | |____[slug].js
```

I have tried using [next-routes](https://github.com/fridays/next-routes), but ran into many issues, including: returned 404 when using getStaticProps or getServerSideProps, returned 404 on refresh of page, returned 404 when url typed in manually.

Does anyone know of a way that I can keep my existing file structure **AND** use dynamic routing? I am open to any options, including continuing to try next-routes if you are aware of working solutions to the aforementioned issues. I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found an answer thanks to help from the [Next.js chat](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/17664), it was recommended to use the built-in [rewrites](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/rewrites) feature provided by Next.js, here is how I implemented that in a nutshell:

1. Updated to Next.js version 9.5.3
2. Set up my next.config.js file like so:

```js
const withSass = require('@zeit/next-sass')
const withTM = require('next-transpile-modules');
const withCSS = require("@zeit/next-css");
const withImages = require('next-images')

const myModule = module.exports = withImages(withSass(withCSS(withTM({
  transpileModules: ['react-bulma-components'],
  sassLoaderOptions: {
    includePaths: ["./src"]
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.css$/i,
        use: ['css-loader'],
      },
    ],
  },
}))));

myModule.rewrites = async () => {
  return [
      { source: '/page/pageType/:slug*', destination: '/FirstDynamicRoutePage' },
  ];
};
```

3. Make sure my custom server was using the Next.js handler as shown in their [docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-server).
4. Use [next/link](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/link) to add my dynamic link where I needed it:

```js
   <Link href={`/page/pageType/${props.pageId}/otherSlug/${props.slug}`}>
        <a>
          {props.name}
        </a>
</Link>
```

That's it! Hopefully this answer can help others with the same question.